# How to add an unusual sender address to Outlook's junk mail facility?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook-2003, spam-prevention

Outlook 2003, XP.

Today I received a 2nd spam email which, when I tried to set a filter through the "Add sender to junk mail", popped up a message that the "email address or domain name is not valid". Obviously someone has a way to bypass normal Outlook capabilities.

Does anyone know how to overcome this?

Comment: I wouldn't bother adding a rule to delete spam emails by email address. Spammers don't use the same for long...

Comment: Further more, spam is often designed so you can create rules to break non-spam emails. EG, we kept getting spam from a company called SID, so we blocked the word SID. The problem was, we worked with a company called Westside ******* and SID (as a word) exists within west*sid*e!

Comment: @DaveRook, that sounds like the [scunthorpe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_Problem) problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do similar to what Nicole suggested, but, just set the rule against any one who doesn't have a valid email address (or the sender is blank/empty). This way, since I assume your customers/clients/colleagues/business contacts etc, all send you email from a real domain, you're only removing those who you don't want.

Comment: I like this - I'll try it.

Comment: I am accepting this - I tried it and a great deal of spam is now, at least, going to the junk folder. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [custom rule](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/create-a-rule-HP005242897.aspx) that deletes the message when it arrives based on other criteria, e.g., content of the message.

Comment: Well, that's possible, but I suspect (I can't tell because I deleted the other message) that there will be no commonality. The message "name" contains a number of characters which I am sure are changed each time and the only thing in the body of the message is 3 announcements that outlook has blocked images. I will keep this message for next time, perhaps there is a commonality. Thanks.